# Qt QML One application, one taskbar entry, multiple windows

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt6, applicationwindow

I create a Qt6 QML application with multiple windows.
I have the main screen (an `ApplicationWindow`) and from there I open (modal) another Window. The two windows are in different Qml files and the first one is set as a parent for the second one. Everything nice and fine.

Now, the problem that I do have is that I have two entries in the Windows OS's taskbar. And I do not want that. I want only one entry for the application.

The second window is an ApplicationWindow, with modality set to `Qt.ApplicationModal` and no flags set.

I tried the flags: `Qt.SubWindow` (not working), `Qt.Tool` (does the taskbar thing but I do not have the standard window buttons: close, minimize, maximize), and those single or in combination with the other flags like `WindowMinMaxButtonsHint` & `WindowCloseButtonHint`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this behavior?

The `MainScreen.qml` looks like this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainScreen
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.Maximized
    ... 
}
```

The `SecondScrren.qml` looks like this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
...
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
    visibility: Window.Maximized
...
}
```

Thanks!